# $(OutDir) is not set to project Output directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a C++/CLI dll project in Visual Studio 2013 where I'm trying to change the output directory. I've set the "Output Directory" setting in Project properties > General to `$(SolutionDir)Stage\$(Configuration)\bin$(PlatformArchitecture)\`. I can see that in the vcxproj file this is reflected to the OutDir:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
  <LinkIncremental>true</LinkIncremental>
  <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)Stage\$(Configuration)\bin$(PlatformArchitecture)\</OutDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

However, it does not seem to actually be *used*. Under Linker > General > Output File the default value is `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`, but the expanded value of `$(OutDir)` seen under Command Line does not reflect the changes I've made, rather it seems to have the value `$(SolutionDir)Stage\$(ConfigurationName)` (`$(ConfigurationName)` is eg "Debug_x64"). This is wierd, since that is not present in the vcxproj-file...

What do I need to do to make the change in Output Directory affect `$(OutDir)`? I have also noticed that there is a macro `$(OutDirWasSpecified)`, which has the value false...

Comment: These macros don't get expanded until you actually build the project.  So use Build + Build and look in your solution directory for the Stage\Debug_x64\binx64\foo.dll file.  Do beware that there is very little hope that the CLR can find it back there.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have built the project, and the files get placed in the wrong place. I have custom assembly loading for these assemblies, so the CLR gets some assistance finding them :)

Comment: I'll try to pull that tooth: *what directory does it get copied to?*

Comment: @HansPassant: The actual expanded value of `$(OutDir)`, `$(SolutionDir)Stage\$(ConfigurationName)`, ie `<slnroot>\Stage\Debug_x64`.

Comment: Well, of course.  Pulling one more time: *what directory does it get copied to?*

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not sure what you are getting to? It is copied there, and as far as I can tell, _only_ there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `$(OutDir)` is typically set in file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.default.props
```

Or alternately, if on a 32-bit platform:

```
...\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.default.props
```

Typically, you'll find in your project file:

**MyProject.vcxproj**

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
```

and if you find the `Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props` file, it will have:

```
 <!-- Allow platforms to define the defaults first -->
 <Import Condition="Exists('$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\$(Platform)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).default.props')" Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Platforms\$(Platform)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).default.props"/>
```

Which is where `$OutDir` gets brought in.

It seems likely that this include-chain is somehow broken, or the original definition of `$(OutDir)` got erased/modified in the file `Microsoft.Cpp.x64.default.props`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look if we somehow mess with the imports

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, my Visual Studio 2013 configuration is a tad different. I have a root folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp`, beneath which are two subfolders, `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120`.